# Difference between CASCADE and RESTRICT? SQL DDL database

Tags: sql, database, ddl

Could anyone tell me what exactly `CASCADE`, and `RESTRICT` mean?
It's in database systems subject to the DDL Part

And what if I don't write any of them in my `ON DELETE` statement?

Answer (score 95):

The `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE RESTRICT` are the foreign key properties and you set them when you create the relationship between two tables.

If you set the relationship to be `ON DELETE CASCADE`, when you run a `DELETE` statement on a "parent" table, it will automatically `DELETE` all the corresponding rows from the "child" table. But the `RESTRICT` (which is the default foreign key relationship behavior) is when you try to delete a row from the "parent" table and there is a row in the "child" table with the same ID, it will fail, complaining about the existing child rows.

Either way, you don't need to mention anything in your `DELETE` clause.

I also wrote a blog post about the different rules for `DELETE` and `UPDATE` commands in more detail here:

[SQL Server Foreign Key Update and Delete Rules | Koukia](https://koukia.ca/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules-556cf09117fe)

Comment: So when i say ON DELETE RESTRICT , the deleted row from the parent table won't get deleted from the other tables?

Comment: when it is set to RESTRICT, none of the rows(parent or child) will be deleted and you will see and error. if you want the parent row to be deleted regardless of the existence of the child rows, you should use NO ACTION then.

Comment: So, **Cascade** means that when i delete the parent the child will get deleted, too. **Restrict** gives me an error when i try to delete. **No Action** doesn't change any thing in the child when i delete the parent. **Set default** sets the child to the default value when i delete the parent. **Set null** sets the child to null when the parent get deleted. am i right? Thank you very much

Comment: well, I just looked it up, looks like NO ACTION and RESTRICT are the same thing, and about the rest, you got it right.

Comment: `ON DELETE NO ACTION` (which is synonymous to `ON DELETE RESTRICT` on some RDBMSes) is the default action so it isn't necessary to write that. You can still delete children of course, you just have to do it explicitly with an extra `DELETE FROM child_table` before `DELETE FROM parent_table`, which I think is the best way.

Comment: restrict and drop comes in the context of dropping table too

Answer (score 37):

There are three types of on delete associated with foreign key

1. On Delete Cascade: when data is removed from a parent table, automatically data deleted from child table (foreign key table).
2. On Delete set Null: when data is removed from a parent table, the foreign key associated cell will be null in a child table.
3. On Delete Restrict: when data is removed from a parent table, and there is a foreign key associated with child table it gives error, you can not delete the record.

Answer (score 3):

CASCADE:
Cascade is used to delete or update the row that is referenced by the foreign key in the parent table. It will delete or update all the rows in the child table that reference the row in the parent table.

RESTRICT:
Restrict is used to restrict the deletion or updating of the row in the parent table that is referenced by the foreign key in the child table. If there are any rows in the child table that reference the row in the parent table, the action (delete/update) will not be executed.

Example:

Table1

| ID | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

Table2

| ID | Product | Category_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product1 | 1 |
| 2 | Product2 | 1 |

Table1 has a foreign key in Table2 (`Category_ID`).

CASCADE:
If we delete row with ID 1 from Table1, then all the rows in Table2 with `Category_ID` 1 will be deleted.

RESTRICT:
If we delete row with ID 1 from Table1, then the deletion will be restricted as there are rows in Table2 with Category_ID 1. The deletion will not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Right so these ON DELETE and ON UPDATE apply to the parent table/row. The reason NO ACTION and RESTRICT are the same thing is because you cannot have a relationship with a child and a parent if the parent doesn't exist.